# Reducing the size of textures

Tags: java, andengine

For my application, I have a texture in high resolution. To reduce the size for small screens I do like that:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResources(){
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    // calculation inSampleSize
    int sm = 1;
    if (cameraWidth+cameraHeight < 1280) sm = 2;// < 800x480
    if (cameraWidth+cameraHeight <  800) sm = 4;// < 480x320
    options.inSampleSize = sm;

    mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(2048/sm, 2048/sm, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    // Loading bitmap
    sky_bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky, options);
    sky_src = new BitmapTextureAtlasSource(sky_bm);

    skyRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(mTexture, sky_src, 0, 0, false);

    mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mTexture);
```

BitmapTextureAtlasSource code:

```
 public class BitmapTextureAtlasSource extends BaseTextureAtlasSource implements IBitmapTextureAtlasSource {

        private Bitmap mBitmap;

        public BitmapTextureAtlasSource(Bitmap pBitmap) {
            super(0,0);
            //this.mBitmap = pBitmap;
            this.mBitmap = pBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return mBitmap.getWidth();
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return mBitmap.getHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public BitmapTextureAtlasSource clone() {
            return new BitmapTextureAtlasSource(Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap));
        }

        public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(Config pBitmapConfig) {
                return mBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public IBitmapTextureAtlasSource deepCopy() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when rotating the screen, I get the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4895
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap is recycled
    at android.opengl.GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLUtils.java:220)
    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:162)
    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:116)
    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:146)
    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:507)
    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
    at net.rbgrn.opengl.GLThread.guardedRun(GLThread.java:235)
    at net.rbgrn.opengl.GLThread.run(GLThread.java:94)
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I would be grateful for any information

Comment: I think the problem may be on BitmapTextureAtlasSource. Could you post its code?

Comment: the other thing I would question is the use of a BitmapTextureAtlas of 2048x2048 - even some high end devices may complain about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be on onLoadBitmap, you should return a copy. I suggest you to try this implementation extending EmptyBitmapTextureAtlasSource:

```
public class BitmapTextureSource extends EmptyBitmapTextureAtlasSource {

private Bitmap mBitmap;

public BitmapTextureSource(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    mBitmap = bitmap;       
}

@Override
public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(Config pBitmapConfig) {
    return mBitmap.copy(pBitmapConfig, true);       
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it works!!! If mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true) insert in the constructor too. Many thanks Rodrigo Dias.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set your resolution policy to `RatioResolutionPolicy` and let the engine do the scaling for you.

http://andengine.wikidot.com/detect-screen-resolution

Comment: Yes, I do it in my application. But I do not want to load large textures for weak devices.

Comment: why not have 2 (or more) different images and load the appropriate one?

Comment: Because if you are supporting a wide range of devices (from 240x320 to 720x1280) you will end up with a very big APK size. If you are using animations, it is a really painful to generate hundreds of files for different resolutions.

Comment: if if if - his example only shows 3 versions and he doesn't mention animations